# Which Timer can I use on the Arduino/Genuino Micro?

Tags: pwm, timers, arduino-micro, atmega32u4

I'm trying to implement charlieplexing with bit angle modulation on my Arduino Micro, and for that I need to use the internal timers.

Which timers of the Atmega32u4 are unused by the standard firmware? Ideally I'd like to use either Timer1 or Timer3 as they have the highest resolution.

Comment: You are using those timers to generate periodic calls so the simplest would work. Aka the use of a 16 bit timers adds no value.

Answer (score 1):

Only Timer0 is used for millis and micros, just as with the Arduino Uno and Mega 2560.

Timer0 is used in "[wiring.c](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c)".
That same file is used for the Uno, Mega 2560, Leonardo and Micro. The differences for the Leonardo is the pin numbers in "[pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo/pins_arduino.h)".

If you don't use PWM output with analogWrite, then you can use all of the other timers. The timers are set to certain values in the function init (also in wiring.c). But you can ignore that if you never use analogWrite.